# Difference between {} and "" in while loop

Tags: while-loop, tcl

I'm trying to figure out why in this example the while loop keeps going on indefinitely. The explanation given is

> If test is placed within quotes, the substitution phase will replace any variables with their current value, and will pass that test to the while command to evaluate, and since the test has only numbers, it will always evaluate the same

I know that normally you would just use curly braces instead of quotes but I want to understand why double quotes are not used. I also understand that double quotes will substitute the values while the curly braces do not.

```
set x 0
while "$x < 5" {
    set x [expr {$x + 1}]
    if {$x > 7} break
    if "$x > 3" continue
    puts "x is $x"
}
```

when I print x within the loop I can see it increment so in the case x is 5. I expect the "set x" line to change the value to 6 and will skip the break line. I expect the x > 3 line to pass how come when it checks "$x < 5" that "6 < 5" still gets interpreted as true?

Comment: aren't you basically setting the while condition to be `0 < 5`, which won't get reevaluated because it is in quotes? eg it doesn't see it as an expression that needs to be reevaluated since it is quotes, but as a simple value (true) which stays that value. like if I said `while true {do some stuff}` there isn't any reason it would check to see if true is still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When tcl tries to evaluate the while statement, the first thing it does is split the statement into words, and substitute anything that's in double quotes or square brackets. Data in curly braces is not substituted.

This happens before the `while` command is called. After this round of substitution, the result of all of the substitutions is passed to the while command as arguments.

Thus, the `while` statement is given two arguments:

1. 0 < 5
2. everything inside the curly braces

`while` sees a static condition that never changes so the loop runs forever.

You should use curly braces so that tcl passes the condition to the `while` command on each iteration:

```
while {$x < 5} { ... }
```

With the above, `while` gets the following arguments:

1. $x < 5
2. everything inside the curly braces